# Why does Tomcat hang while trying to setAutoCommit on MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have a recurring, intermittent issue where my Spring JPA/Hibernate app (running on Tomcat 8) will hang for 5-30 seconds while trying to read from MySQL, during the setAutoCommit phase.  This happened when we were running MySQL 5.0, and still continues after upgrading to the latest MariaDB.

The issue may not appear for days or weeks at a time, but when it does, it's generally in the afternoon, M-Th, during our "peak" hours.  ("Peak" here is really fairly light, maybe 10 requests per second.)  Strangely enough, the issue often happens right at 14:50, though I can't find any cronjobs or other recurring tasks that would cause this.

The app is clustered across two servers, and both servers hang at the same time while trying to connect to the shared db server, so it seems to be something on the database side.  The db allows 1000 max_connections, but is using nowhere near that many.  On the Tomcat side, I'm using C3P0 with 100 max connections. There doesn't seem to be any particular SQL that triggers the issue, all queries hang while this issue is happening.

Here's the stack trace for a hung thread:

```
"ajp-nio-8010-exec-26" Id=1355 RUNNABLE (in native)
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:100)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:143)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:173)
   - locked com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream@33d807d4
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2911)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3332)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3322)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3762)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
   - locked com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@178ec6c
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4852)
   - locked com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@178ec6c
   at com.intergral.fusionreactor.jdbc.ConnectionSurrogate.setAutoCommit(ConnectionSurrogate.java:368)
   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:1059)
   etc.....
```

And at the same moment, in MySQL's slow query log:

```
# Time: 160128 14:50:38
# User@Host: user @ server1
# Thread_id: 77244  Schema: db_live  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 7.621437  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1454010638;
commit;
# User@Host: user @ server2
# Thread_id: 81339  Schema: db_live  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 7.556022  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1454010638;
commit;
```

I'm not quite sure that to make of the slow log - there's no actual SQL here, but it corresponds to the 7-second hang observed on Tomcat at this time.  Something to do with both servers trying to connect at the same time and blocking each other?  Both `SET timestamp` statements are exactly the same.  Note that both Tomcat instances log in with the same user credentials, just from two different IPs.  There no other slow queries nearby in the logs, before or after.

Any ideas what might cause this or where to look next?

Edit:

Other details that may be worth noting: the tables are InnoDB, and we're using `transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED`.  All the threads hanging are waiting on setAutoCommit.

Comment: Sounds like you already concluded it's an issue on the database server side, and I concur from your description, so it's not a programming issue on the client side, aka application server side, so this question is misplaced. Sounds more like a question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: c3p0: the non-production connection pool everyone uses in production for some reason. Why does everyone use that thing?

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show on the db server side? When `setAutoCommit` is being set, are you beginning a transaction or committing one?

Comment: Looks like it is beginning the transaction - I can see `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin` on the stack.  What connection pool would you suggest?  I looked at BoneCP but it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Comment: ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78710

Comment: qxo - Thanks for the tip, but we're not doing any replication, so I don't think that's it.  FWIW, we moved from c3p0 to HikariCP last month, and we haven't seen the issue since.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. The stack trace show that it is *blocked* trying to *read* from the database server, which implies that it has already connected, and that what it is doing is setting `autoCommit`, not anything in the connect phase.

Comment: Yes, the question is more accurately phrased as "setAutoCommit on MySQL" instead of "connect to MySQL".  I have made it so.